# PowerShell: write value in a input type=file Form.

Tags: html, internet-explorer, powershell, file-upload, input

I have a **input type=text** inputboxes on a webpage I load and fill with values and click the submit button which works fine:

```
$ie=New-Object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible=$true 
$ie.Navigate("https://myurl/test.html") 
while($ie.busy){Start-Sleep 1} 
$ie.Document.getElementById("field_firstName").value="Firstname" 
$ie.Document.getElementById("field_lastName").value="Lastname" 
$ie.Document.getElementById("btn_upload").Click() 
while($ie.busy){Start-Sleep 1}
```

I'd also like to populate a **input type=file** box with c:\temp\test.txt and upload this.
I read that because of security reasons the value= is not supported from the browsers.

Is there any workaround to do this with PowerShell?
Maybe "click" the browse button and select the file or use sendkeys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [Jaykul's post](http://huddledmasses.org/using-powershell-and-watin-powerwatin/). He uses Watin for automation. Just download the assembly and try. I was able to set the value and then submit the form like this:

```
$WatinPath = 'c:\bin\watin\WatiN.Core.dll' #path with downloaded assembly
$watin     = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom( $WatinPath )

$ie        = new-object WatiN.Core.IE("https://myurl/test.html")
$file1 = $ie.FileUpload('file1') #id of the input
$file1.set('C:\temp\test.txt') # path to the file

# and now just find the button and click on it
$o = $ie.Button('send') #send is id of the submit button
$o.Click()
```

I understand your reasons to use IE instead of `WebClient` and similar classes, however use them in other cases if possible.

**Edit:**

In case you don't have ID of the element, but only the name, you can try

```
$f = $ie.FileUpload({param($fu) $fu.GetAttributeValue("name") -eq 'the name you have' })
```

or

```
$f = $ie.FileUploads | ? { $_.GetAttributeValue("name") -eq 'the name you have' }
```

Comment: This looks good, although i have Problems to find the correct field as the source has no id but just a name... Do you know if i can search by name and not by id?

Comment: I used your example where you call function getElementById, so I thought you know the id. I'll check if it is possible.

Comment: I am also confused why my first example worked bacause there i also just have a name and no id tag...

With your last example  $_.GetAttributeValue("name") it seems that i find the box but my submitbutton (also no id just name) didn't worked. Have to play with that again tommorrow. Thank you so far

Comment: You have to find the submit button similarly like the file upload: `$sub = $ie.Button({param($fu) $t.GetAttributeValue("name") -eq 'name of submit button' })` I don't know it exactly, I cann't examine it now. Just try `$ie | gm` and you will find the right method ;)

Comment: This worked! Thanks!
In the watin lists i found:
ie.FileUpload(Find.ByName("ctl02$myfile")).Set("test.txt)
But i couldn't get the Find.ByName working.. I'll yous your suggested solution now.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly consider using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28VS.80%29.aspx)or [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) instead of driving the IE GUI.  There is a [WebClient example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28VS.80%29.aspx#ctl00_WikiContent_ctl00_HeaderTitle) using PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks for response, Matthew. 
Although i'd prefer IE Gui at the moment as i can see the results then and avoid problems with proxy's certificates etc.. i would be intrested how the posted code above would look like with a webclient approach..

Comment: It looks like you may not be able to do what you want with pure WebClient.  There is a function at CodeProject (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/uploadfileex.aspx) you could look at.  It's basically a more sophisticated version of WebClient.UploadFile, based on HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would have to use the SendKeys route if you want to do this in IE. Direct text-entry into the box is blocked in IE8 and higher.